# what is dllhost.exe in windows xp, and can I delete it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, task-manager

I'm trying to figure out what are all processes working right now in the task manager of my computer (Windows xp).

I'm wondering what does dllhost.exe actually does and if I can get rid of it without making the computer crash...?

Comment: The file you are asking about is a critical system file and should not be removed.  The file in question is harmless and is not the source of your problems.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm answering another question of yours :)

### What is dllhost.exe?

The original `dllhost.exe` from Microsoft is an important part of Windows. The file `dllhost.exe` is located in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder. The `dllhost.exe` file is a Windows system file.

> The term dllhost.exe *32, also known as dllhost.exe *32 COM Surrogate,
>   is a process used to host one or more operating system services. The
>   dllhost.exe *32 Microsoft Windows executable file is labeled as: COM
>   Surrogate. This is a required Windows file and is used to load needed
>   DLL files that are used with Microsoft Windows and Windows programs
>   that run on your computer. This file is located in either the
>   c:\windows\system32 or c:\winnt\system32 directories depending on your
>   version of Windows and may also be located in the dllcache directory
>   if present.

Source - http://malwaretips.com/blogs/dllhost-exe-32-com-surrogate-removal/

### Is dllhost.exe a virus?

No, it is not. The true `dllhost.exe` file is a safe Microsoft Windows system process, called **COM Surrogate**. However, writers of malware programs, such as viruses, worms, and Trojans deliberately give their processes the same file name to escape detection.

### Should you delete dllhost.exe?

Dynamic Link Library (DLL) files are executable files used to allocate resources for performing software tasks. In other words, DLL files help programs work properly in Windows. The program `dllhost.exe` is used in conjunction with many DLL files to passively manage and access DLL files. Without a functioning DLL host file, your computer's operating system could become unstable, resulting in the dreaded blue screen of death. Under normal operating circumstances, you should **never** get rid of `dllhost.exe`.

Comment: You bet! I keep on asking this questions because they are missing here... You think that's ok ?

Comment: Your answers are far better than the ones in Google ;)

Comment: You can ask as many questions as you like as long as they meet the requirements  > http://superuser.com/help/on-topic And thank you ;) Glad you like my answers! :D